# What is a Triple-decker word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

I have a rule which makes a word a triple-decker word™.

Use my list below to see if you can figure out the rule:

| Triple-decker Words™ | Not Triple-decker Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| BABOON | CAPUCHIN |
| RAVINE | CREVASSE |
| REFERS | IMPLIES |
| BOUGHT | STOLE |
| EMBLAZONRY | EMBROIDERY |
| FIVERS | TENNERS |
| FANS | NEUTRALS |
| EARNER | MOOCHER |
| GNAT | ANT |

Text-only version:

```
Triple-decker Words™, Not Triple-decker Words™
BABOON,CAPUCHIN
RAVINE,CREVASSE
REFERS,IMPLIES
BOUGHT,STOLE
EMBLAZONRY,EMBROIDERY
FIVERS,TENNERS
FANS,NEUTRALS
EARNER,MOOCHER
GNAT,ANT
```

This puzzle can be solved by testing the Triple-decker words™ without using the non-triple-decker words™.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are "TRIPLE-DECKER WORDS" a triple-decker word and "NON-TRIPLE-DECKER WORDS" a non-triple-decker word? I assume they are not

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. As far as I know there isn't already such a thing as a triple-decker word already. There is a specific set of words I am thinking of, which triple-decker words are part of and non-triple-decker words are not in this set.

Comment: But is the first line included in the list or is it not?

Comment: Oh, apologies - no, triple-decker words isn't a triple-decker word. Coincidentally, non-triple-decker words is a non-triple-decker word.

Comment: I've applied something like the usual template. I hope this clarifies the issue discussed above.

Comment: (The formatting isn't quite right -- for me, at least, it looks OK while editing and goes wrong when displayed normally. I think @Rubio is the expert here; the template was his originally. Perhaps he will drop by and figure out what's wrong. Or maybe it's just my browser being odd.)

Comment: It looks fine to me, hopefully just a browser issue.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Sometimes a page reload is needed to make it look right, especially when it's input piecemeal. But it looks fine now :)

Comment: Yup, looks OK to me too now. I wonder what was going on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Triple Decker words are surely

> Words that are anagrams of themselves when [rot13'd](http://rot13.com/).

Triple Deckers:

> ```
>        REFERS -> ERSREF               RAVINE -> ENIVAR
>          FANS -> SNAF                   GNAT -> TANG
>        EARNER -> RNEARE               BABOON -> ONOBBA
>        FIVERS -> SVIREF           EMBLAZONRY -> RZOYNMBAEL
>        REFERS -> ERSREF               BOUGHT -> OBHTUG
> ```

Comment: (I've formatted your word list with `<pre>` inside the spoiler. If you don't like it, roll back. Unfortunately, markup inside spoiler tags is a bit tricky.)

Comment: Correct! Hope you enjoyed the puzzle.

Comment: So why are they called "triple-decker words"?

Comment: @BálintBudavölgyi I think it's because "decker" sounds a lot like "deca", and "triple" + "deca" ...

Comment: @MOehm Thanks!! I still haven't quite figured out all the formatting tricks yet but that's a neat way to do it :)

Comment: @Hellion correct, I was going to go with triskadeka-words but thought that would be a little bit too obvious.

Comment: I was going for something totally different, with the word 'deck', I looked at which letters had a 'top platform' in their shape on which you could make a deck :) and quite a few have 3!